# Facebook custom story, #100 Object Missing a Required Value... property 'appnamespace:prop' of type 'string' was not provided."

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

For a Custom Story, using user-owned objects (no URL for FB to parse) I defined the custom properties yet I get an error #100...

here's the code:

```
FB.api(
  'me/objects/appnamespace:CustomStory',
  'post',
  { object:
    { 
    "title": "story title",    
    "t_name":"watching FOX news",
    "main_a": "custom prop 1",
    "main_b": "custom prop 2",
    "description": "test post tracked trigger"
     }
   },
  function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
);
```

error says appnamespace:CustomStory  property main_a not defined
which is odd because it's right there...

thanks in advance for ideas...

Answer (score 0):

oh.... so the fix is to enclose custom properties in a "data" property that holds an Object ala:

```
FB.api(
  'me/objects/appnamespace:CustomStory',
  'post',
  { object:
    {"title": "storty title",
    "data": {                      // put custom property values here
        "main_a": "value 1",
        "main_b": "value 2",
        "t_name": "another property"
    },
   "description": "test post tracked trigger"
     }
   },
  function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
);
```